# Changing ORDER BY direction causes performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I use MySQL 5.6, and I have two tables each with 16M rows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newsstudios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=16855382 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newsstudio_categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `newsstudio_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `newsstudio_id` (`newsstudio_id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `newsstudio_id_category_id` (`newsstudio_id`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=16864013 ;
```

I have one query with order by `order by newsstudios.id ASC` :

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id FROM `newsstudios` WHERE exists 
(
  select newsstudio_id from newsstudio_categories 
  where newsstudios.id=newsstudio_categories.newsstudio_id 
  and newsstudio_categories.category_id in (1303,1313,1323,1333,1343,632)
) 
order by newsstudios.id limit 5;
```

the result of this query is:

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|   27 |
|   47 |
|   87 |
|  110 |
|  181 |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.19 sec)
```

but when I change the direction of order by to `DESC` the query execution time decreases 100 times:

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 98232|
| 98111|
| 95222|
| 88132|
| 78181|
+------+
5 rows in set (21 sec)
```

First: why does this change in the direction of order by cause this huge difference in performance?

Second: before this query I have tried `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE IN` queries instead of `WHERE EXISTS` but they have duplicate result that I should use `GROUP BY` that it cause `using filesort` and `using temporary` which decreases performance a lot. Do you have any suggestions for the query to have better performance?

Comment: Have you tested if adding an index with reverse order `(category_id,newsstudio_id)` is used (and what the efficiency is in that case)?

Comment: I will try `(category_id,newsstudio_id)` this index, but it's weird for me that why changing the order direction causes decreasing performance.

Comment: The decreased efficiency is probably because of coincidence. More rows with small ids happen to have one `category_id in (1303,1313,1323,1333,1343,632)` while rows with high ids do not (happen). So larger parts of the `newsstudio_categories (newsstudio_id, category_id)` have to be searched until 5 matching rows are found.

Comment: I tried (category_id,newsstudio_id), it don't improve performance but also decrease it.
Do you have any suggestion(another query or schema) to fetch this result more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the different categories you are searching on are not to many and you can build the more complex query, this will use an index on `(category_id, newsstudio_id)` and I'd expect it to  be more efficient than your previous query, with either `ASC` or `DESC` choice.

It's a bit more complex to construct and I'd expect efficiency to degrade if the number of categories are tens or hundreds:

```
SELECT newsstudio_id
FROM 
  ( ( SELECT newsstudio_id  FROM newsstudio_categories  WHERE category_id = 1303
      ORDER BY newsstudio_id DESC  LIMIT 5 
    ) 
    UNION 
    ( SELECT newsstudio_id  FROM newsstudio_categories  WHERE category_id = 1313
      ORDER BY newsstudio_id DESC  LIMIT 5 
    )
      ...
    UNION
    ( SELECT newsstudio_id  FROM newsstudio_categories  WHERE category_id = 632
      ORDER BY newsstudio_id DESC  LIMIT 5 
    )
  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY newsstudio_id DESC
LIMIT 5 ;
```

Comment: Faster than the 0.19 seconds of your first query?

Comment: yeah, about 0.008

Answer (score 2):

As ypercube said in his comment, your index should perform better in this case if the fields are reversed.

Also, as long as every `newsstudio_categories`.`newsstudio_id` has at least one matching row in `newsstudios`.`id` (not guaranteed by your schema, but it seems likely), then you could get by with a query that only looks at `newsstudio_categories`

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT `newsstudio_id` AS id FROM
newsstudio_categories
WHERE newsstudio_categories.category_id in (1303 , 1313, 1323, 1333, 1343, 632)
ORDER BY `newsstudio_id` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

or

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `newsstudio_id` AS id FROM
newsstudio_categories
WHERE newsstudio_categories.category_id in (1303 , 1313, 1323, 1333, 1343, 632)
GROUP BY `newsstudio_id`
ORDER BY `newsstudio_id` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: As I said in question I try these queries before but this queries cause filesort and temporary table that decrease performance a lot.